# Examples of short maps (Lipschitz functions with $k=1$) with exactly 2 fixed points.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I was just reading about the Banach fixed point theorem, which states that a contraction (a function $f$ satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq k|x-y|$ for $0<k<1$) has a unique fixed point.

If we have $k=1$ then $f$ is called a short map or a non-expansive map. I'm wondering how many fixed points such functions can have. Clearly if $f$ is the identity function then every point is a fixed point. If $f$ just translates points then there are no fixed points.

Does there exist a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$, which has exactly two fixed points? If not are there examples of short maps involving different metric spaces with exactly two fixed points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ exists.  Indeed, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is short and $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ with $a<b$.  Then for any $c\in (a,b)$, $f(c)=c$, since if $d<c$ then $|d-b|>|c-b|$ and if $d>c$ then $|d-a|>|c-a|$.  So if $f$ fixes two points, it must also fix the entire interval between them.

However, there are many examples in other metric spaces.  For instance, taking $S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$ with the induced metric from $\mathbb{C}$ (or the arc length metric), $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is an isometry $S^1\to S^1$ which fixes only $1$ and $-1$.  Or more trivially, if $X$ is a metric space with two points, then the identity map works.

Comment: Interesting, that seems pretty obvious now that you say it. Do you think there is an example from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: No, a similar argument applies to any convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$: if $f$ fixes two points, it must fix the entire segment between them.

Comment: Awesome, thank you :)